# CarouselView Demo

Tags: android, android-layout, carousel

Hi Guys i have implemented CarouselView in my application from [here](http://horribile.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-3d-carousel.html)

[image: screenshot of the view]

I want to place the view in the center of the screen. Can you tell me how i can do that. I tried to change the main layout.

Here's how my main layout looks like right now:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.demo.main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.demo.controls.Carousel
    android:id="@+id/cvMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animationDuration="200"
    android:gravity="top"
    pj:Items="@array/entries"
    pj:Names="@array/names"
    pj:SelectedItem="0"
    pj:UseReflection="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: here you are setting images from xml , is it posiible to set image from java file ??

Comment: Helo have you got any fix for this??

Answer (score 0):

Just as simple as changing this: `android:gravity="top"` to `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: as you can see even though i have gravity set to top the view is in the bottom. so the gravity attribute is not working because of some reason.

Comment: as your image is cropped I couldn't have noticed that. You can also try to play around with the layout_gravity attribute to the parent component, i.e. your parent `LinearLayout`

Comment: image is not cropped, thats a screenshot from the emulator.